# What's the difference between if/else and try catch(exception)?

Tags: c++

for example this code
I can do it like this, this is simple if / else

```
if (age>=18)
cout << "Access granted - you are old enough.";
else {
    cout << "Access denied - You must be at least 18 years old.\n";
    cout << "Age is: " << age;  
}
```

and this is the "same code" with exception

```
try {
  int age = 15;
  if (age >= 18) {
    cout << "Access granted - you are old enough.";
  } else {
    throw (age);
  }
}
catch (int myNum) {
  cout << "Access denied - You must be at least 18 years old.\n";
  cout << "Age is: " << myNum;
}
```

why would I use exception if I can do the same code without exception?

Comment: Nobody would use exceptions in that case. Exceptions are supposed to travel through the call stack to notify a caller that something went wrong.

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated languages. If your question is not related to a specific language use the `language-agnostic` tag.

Comment: "why would I use exception if I can do the same code without exception?" your question is not quite clear. Do you mean why would you use exception in this particular situation? Or in general?

Comment: i thought mt question is pretty clear, and somehow -6, i dont understand this site al all

Comment: *"why would I use exception if I can do the same code without exception?"* -- this is a good question to ask every time you are tempted to throw an exception. Well, first find out if you can get the same result without an exception, then ask yourself the question.

Comment: Your question gets downvoted because you could and should just Google "why use exceptions" and spend a couple of hours reading and playing around with them.

Comment: I think it's a no-brainer to use the first version, and I really don't understand why anyone would consider using exceptions in this case. But I say this with some years of moderate C++ experience. I won't downvote, because I remember how I started coding ... :D

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either to be honest. Have a compensating upvote! And I don't necessarily agree with the dogma that litters this page. What you present is a precursor to "duck typing" - if it looks like an adult and quacks like an adult then it is an adult. In other words, treat it as an adult and raise exceptions if it isn't. That's almost Pythonic.

Comment: An advantage of exceptions is they 'jump' back through function calls until a catch.  On the way all local objects are cleanly destructed. With function calls several levels deep, no if/else clauses on every intermediate level for just forwarding an error are needed. Lots of errors can happen deep down: no more RAM, disk removed, ... It would need a check each time memory is allocated (happens often in the background just by using std::string). It is easier to handle those (+ your user-defined) errors en bloc.

Comment: In your example there are currently no advantages of try catch, as you have the else clause anyway and catch in the same function instead of on another level. But apart from that there is nothing wrong in general. If your processing is a bit more convoluted, using exceptions could help with readability.

Answer (score 3):

> why would I use exception if I can do the same code without exception?

Typically, you wouldn't.

Exceptions should very rarely be used to control the "normal" flow of a program. They are supposed to be *exceptions* to the normal flow and checking that the entered age is 18 or above is most probably to be considered normal. If you somehow didn't get *any* age at all, that would be exceptional.

Example:

```
try {
    age = get_age();              // may throw
    name = get_name();            // may throw
    shoe_size = get_shoe_size();  // may throw
    ...
    ... work with the data gathered without checking that each function succeeded ...
}
catch(...) {
    one of the functions failed to collect the data needed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> why would I use exception if I can do the same code without exception?

You typically wouldn't throw if you could do the same without it. Your code is a good example of a case where you shouldn't throw.

You would typically throw in cases where you cannot elegantly do same code without throwing.